# C# Getting Data from .txt File separated with Semicolons

Tags: c#, text-files

By Example I have a .txt File with this content:

```
Hello;Test;StackOverflow;I live here
Hi;NoTest;StackOverflow;I don't live here
```

and so on..

Now I would like to read the txtFile, but I don't want to read the "whole" line or
everthing.. only to the next semicolon.. till the end of a Line..

one StringVariable for one Word in the txtFile but just for one line..

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you want to read a full line? Are the lines prohibitively long? i.e. hundreds of megabytes?

Comment: Well you always have to read/search for the semicolon. So why not read the whole line and then Split it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read text line by line like this:

```
var streamReader = new StreamReader(new FileStream("c:\\file.txt"));
var line = streamReader.ReadLine();

var values = line.Split(';');
```

and then read any value from line like this:

```
var value = values[2];
```

And if you want to iterate throught those values you can make it like this:

```
var streamReader = new StreamReader(new FileStream("c:\\file.txt"));

while(!streamReader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = streamReader.ReadLine()
    var values = line.Split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(values[i]); //example usage
}

streamReader.Dispose();
```

Comment: thank you 4 the answer, I will try it! If it works, I will mark the answer as answered

Comment: I wrote this code from the back of my head, so if something won't compile then please let me know..

Comment: A couple of small issues in there - your for loop is incrementing `line`, not `i`, and there's a typo on `Lenght`.  Also, I would recommend the use of `using` around the StreamReader, so that it's automatically disposed, and I believe checking `streamReader.EndOfStream` is a slightly better way of checking if you've reached the end of the file.

Comment: Great suggestions.. thanks.. as I said.. I was making this solution at hoc :)